# Ansible: Perform Cleanup on Task Failure

Tags: ansible

I'm currently writing an Ansible play that follows this general format and is run via a cron job:

```
pre_tasks:
  -Configuration / package installation

tasks:
  -Work with installed packages

post_tasks:
  -Cleanup / uninstall packages
```

The problem with the above is that sometimes a command in the `tasks` section fails, and when it does the `post_tasks` section doesn't run, leaving the system in a messy state. Is it possible to force the commands in `post_tasks` to run even if a failure **or fatal error** occurs?

My current approach is to apply `ignore_errors: yes` to everything under the `tasks` section, and then apply a `when:` conditional to each task to individually check if the prior command succeeded.

This solution seems like a hack, but it gets worse because even with `ignore_errors: yes` set, if a Fatal error is encountered for a task the entire play will still immediately fail, so I have to also run a cron'd bash script to manually check on things after reach play execution.

All I want is a guarantee that even if `tasks` fails, `post_tasks` will still run. I'm sure there is a way to do this without resorting to bash script wrappers.

Comment: Unfortunately (for your use case) `post_tasks` is not intended as a cleanup. Quoting the ansible lead: "Pre tasks and post tasks are largely designed for working with load balancers." (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3869)

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Don't use `post_tasks` block but rather have your cleanup process as part of regular `tasks`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  If something fails, you're saying that every task in your playbook needs to `ignore_errors: yes` because Ansible has no discernable way to do any sort of post_cleanup?  Doesn't a playbook by it's own admission, halt on the first error?  How will the cleanup task get run?

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: @Zasz solution to what?

Comment: Guaranteed execution of a task at the end of the playbook. Kind of like a finally at the end of try-catch block.

I am moving my ansible logs to another location at the end of playbook execution. I need this to happen even if playbook fails.

Comment: @Zasz I am looking for a solution to the same problem, all of the current solutions I have found are very hackish.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4443 we will get that feature in v2. In the meantime you could try using a callback plugin like this one https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180 and put some logic in there as workaround

Answer (score 60):

This feature became available in Ansible 2.0:

[This is the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_blocks.html) for the new stanza markers `block`, `rescue`, and `always`.

Comment: I suggest changing this to the accepted answer, as the currently accepted one is wrong, @Mark

Answer (score 3):

You should use handlers (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html) and set:

> force_handlers: true

Please give a look to KubeNow's integration test (https://github.com/kubenow/KubeNow/blob/master/test/integration-test.yml).

Answer (score 3):

@MarkTamsky is right, but here's also a quick explanation.

You can group multiple tasks into `block`s and then task directives will be one level deeper (like the code in a "try" block in most OO languages), and at the higher level, you can control what happens if one or more of these block tasks fail(s) with `rescue`(like "catch"es after "try" blocks).

Also if you need some tasks to run at the end of the execution of the block tasks (i.e., no matter whether those block tasks fail or not) you can use `always` (like Python's "finally").

**Example**(directly copied from the documentation):

```yaml
- name: Attempt and graceful roll back demo

  block: # <--- a block of tasks
    - name: Print a message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'I execute normally'

    - name: Force a failure
      ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false

    - name: Never print this
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'I never execute, due to the above task failing, :-('

  rescue: # <--- a rescue
    - name: Print when errors
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'I caught an error'

    - name: Force a failure in middle of recovery! >:-)
      ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false

    - name: Never print this
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'I also never execute :-('

  always: # <--- an always
    - name: Always do this
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "This always executes"
```

NOTICE 1: Each block must be in a "tasks", i.e.:

```yaml
 tasks:
   - name: some name
     block:
       - name: some name
         <module>
```

[NOTICE 2:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#grouping-tasks-with-blocks) Every directive (e.g. `when`, `become`, etc.) at the block level will be applied to "each of the tasks in the block one by one" and not to the block itself.