# How can I perform ansible error-handling at playbook level?

Tags: error-handling, ansible

I have a main playbook which imports other playbooks to perform actions in several machines.
machine1 is a hub where test results are collected, after being executed on other machines:

```
- name: clear state
  import_playbook: playbook-clear-machines-state.yml
 
- name: prepare run
  hosts: machine1
  roles:
    - prepare_test_run
    
- name: run_tests_in_machine2
  import_playbook: playbook-run-tests-machine2.yml
  ignore_error: yes
  
  ...
```

What I would like to guarantee is that only an instance is running at a time (i.e. no one is able to run tests if an user is already doing so).
I thought of using a lock file in machine1 as a way of preventing that, in the following manner:

```
- name: check temp file
  hosts: machine1
  tasks:
    - name: get stats of lock file
      stat:
        path: ./ansible.lock
      register: st
    - fail:
        msg: "tests already running"
      when:
        - st.stat.isreg is defined and st.stat.isreg
    - name: create lock file
      file:
        path: ./ansible.lock
        state: touch
        
- name: run all tests
  import_playbook: playbook-main.yml      
  ignore_errors: yes
  
- name: delete lock file
  hosts: machine1
  tasks:
    - name: delete ansible.lock file
      file:
        path: ./ansible.lock
        state: absent
```

The problem here is that I need to make sure the lock file is always deleted in the end - even if there was an error at an earlier play.
How could I accomplish this? I tried to look into blocks and handlers but they don't seem appropriate to use at this level. Can anybody point me to a strategy/way to accomplish this?

Many thanks, José.

Answer (score 0):

For this needs, you have rescue and always mechanism that must corresponding to your use case.
You have more details [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html).

So with your example code, this must looks like this :

```
- name: check temp file
  hosts: machine1
  tasks:
    - name: get stats of lock file
      stat:
        path: ./ansible.lock
      register: st
    - fail:
        msg: "tests already running"
      when:
        - st.stat.isreg is defined and st.stat.isreg
    - name: run all tests
      block:
        - name: create lock file
          file:
            path: ./ansible.lock
            state: touch
        - name: 'playbook-main.yml'
          # import_playbook: playbook-main.yml
          # Paste the content of this playbook here
          ignore_errors: yes
      always:
        - name: delete lock file
          file:
            path: ./ansible.lock
            state: absent
```

In a context really close to you, you have this [reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875377/ansible-perform-cleanup-on-task-failure) to.

Comment: After refactoring my code as per your answer, I'm getting the following error: ERROR! this task 'import_playbook' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: ansible.builtin.include_role, ansible.builtin.win_shell, ansible.builtin.set_fact, script, ansible.legacy.command, ansible.legacy.group_by (...). Could it be because the imported playbook makes references to the other hosts?

Comment: Yes currently, my answer does't work cause by limitation of import_playbook in doc it's illustrate. I advise to pu the content of this playbook in the block if it's possible or to package a dedicated role to this